# How to use Perl's FreezeThaw to thaw an object and then call object methods on it?

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl's [Calendar](http://search.cpan.org/~yewenbin/Calendar-v0.4.2/lib/Calendar.pm) module to create a "date", and I want to serialize this data to a text file and then get it back.

I'm trying to use [FreezeThaw](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/FreezeThaw-0.5001/FreezeThaw.pm) to accomplish this. Thus, this is what I have so far:

```
my $date = Calendar->new_from_Gregorian((localtime)[4] + 1, (localtime)[3], (localtime)[5]+1900);
$string = freeze $date;
print $string."\n";
$olddata = thaw $string;
print $olddata->date_string."\n";
```

And I get back:

```
FrT;@1|>>0|$19|Calendar::Gregorian%8|$8|absolute$3|day$5|month$4|year$6|734599$1|6$1|4$4|2012
Can't call method "date_string" on an undefined value at calendar.pl line 23.
```

My question is: how do I get the thawed value back into a usable Calendar object, so that I can call methods like `$olddata->date_string?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `thaw` in list context. This can be achieved by changing

```
my $olddata = thaw $string;
```

to

```
my ($olddata) = thaw $string;
```

I have just filed a bug [report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=76175) concerning this questionable need.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign to a list.

```
my $date = Calendar->new_from_Gregorian((localtime)[4] + 1, (localtime)[3], (localtime)[5]+1900);
my $string = freeze $date;
say $string;
my( $olddata ) = thaw $string;
say $olddata->date_string;
```

It's expecting multiple objects to freeze:

```
use Business::ISBN;
use Calendar;
use Data::Dumper;
use FreezeThaw qw(freeze thaw);

my $isbn = Business::ISBN->new( '0596004923' );
my $date = Calendar->new_from_Gregorian((localtime)[4] + 1, (localtime)[3], (localtime)[5]+1900);

my $string = freeze( $date, $isbn );
say $string;

my( $olddata, $oldisbn ) = thaw $string;
say $olddata->date_string;
say $oldisbn->as_string;
```

The `return` statement in `thaw` ends with:

```
return @$ref;
```

In scalar context, that's evaluated to the number of elements in the array, so you're getting `1` when you expect an object. You shouldn't have to know this, and FreezeThaw should warn you that you've called it incorrectly. It's the difference between these two:

```
my $value = return_array();
say "Return array: $value";  # 3

$value = return_list();
say "Return list: $value"; # Roscoe

sub return_array {
    my $array = [ qw(Buster Mimi Roscoe) ];
    return @$array;
    }

sub return_list {
    return qw(Buster Mimi Roscoe) ;
    }
```